# print or write to file "\040"(space) in python

Tags: python, linux

**Background:**

I need to write following line to `fstab` file using python

```
//10.1.1.1//First\040Second /Mount cifs ------
```

**Problem :**

But this `First Second` is coming from input and when I try to convert it into `First\040Second` it's printing same as `First Second`.

**Question :**

How can I convert `First Second` into `First\040Second` , simply replace the `" "` into `\040` ?

Note : Even when I try to print `First\040Second`, it shows as `First Second` only.

```
print "First Second".replace(" ", "\040")
```

Thanks in advance, If you need more clarification I can provide.

Comment: Are you sure this is what you want to do? `\0` means something.

Comment: yes it is working (I mean mounting the samba drive properly). But still I do not have a good idea about the `\0`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
 print "First Second".replace(" ", "\040")
```

to

```
 print "First Second".replace(" ", "\\040")
```

`\\` is the proper way to print a backslash

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_character

EDIT: Starrify  enlighted me and basically said that \xxx or \040 was treated as a hexidecimal

Comment: "\0 is the null char" is there anything related with `\0`?

Comment: @ starrify, I barely understand how python works. It too complicated for me. All I know is that \0 was a classic way to end a string from c

Comment: @user1462442 Well my point is that, `\0` has nothing to do with this case. As the OP writes `'\040'`, it is a single character whose ASCII value is 40 in base 8, not a character `'\0'` and two characters `'40' `followed. Also there are escapes for base 16 like `'\xAB'` where AB is a hexadecimal number. This escaping rule is used in both C and Python.

Comment: @user1462442 Absolutely not since it's good and helpful. :) An edit is enough I guess.

Answer (score 0):

First, in Python, `" " == "\040"` is always `True` as the latter one is just another form of expressing characters in a string.

As I understand you want to print visually escaping for characters, then please use `"First Second".replace(" ", "\\040")`, where `"\\040"` could be also replaced by `r"\040"`, as "r" here means [raw string literals](http://docs.python.org/3.4/reference/lexical_analysis.html#literals) in Python.

Answer (score 0):

Escape the sequence by adding a `\` before `\040`: `First\\040Second`

Answer (score 0):

You can prefix the string with `r` to denote that it is a raw string:

```
>>> s = r'First\040Secon'
>>> print s
First\040Secon
>>> s
'First\\040Secon'
```